# Setting the font size in Itextpdf

Tags: java, pdf, ascii, itext

I am working on a program where I am taking an `ASCII` file as input and converting it to `PDF` using `Itext` library.

I am able to convert and print it, but the font size appears too small. Currently I have set the font size to `6` but, if I change it to 7, It doesn't work, it doesn't fit on the `PDF` properly.

Here is a part of my code snippet:

```
  Document doc= new Document();
    Rectangle test = new Rectangle(531,666);
    doc = new Document(test); 
    doc.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
    p = new Paragraph(new Phrase(lineSpacing,line,
                   FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize)));
    doc.add(p);
```

I am not able to use double with this method. Is there any other way?

Comment: `Doesn't fit` means it outstretches your page? A screenshot of 6 and 7 would help

Comment: @PopoFibo :- Hi, I keep my fontsize and linespacing equal in my program i.e. if fontsize = 6 then linespacing = 6 as well. But, even if I set fontsize = 7 and linespacing  = 6 the output is same. How can I attach files here?

Comment: Ok here are the attached snaps:- For 6:- <a href = "http://sdrv.ms/1aqXadF"> For 7:- <a href="http://sdrv.ms/19vYxJz">

Comment: *I am not able to use double with this method* - the method signature is `public static Font getFont(final String fontname, final float size)`; thus try using a `float fntSize` or cast your `double fntSize` to `(float)`.

Comment: Yes, it does help. But now I am having a problem with Margins. Even if I set the margins to 0,0,0,0 using the above method or directly using Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(540, 560f), 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);  I am getting white blank space on the top and bottom. I am setting the margins before opening the document. Any help?

Comment: Ok, got it. If I use PageSize.A4,0f,0f,0f,0f and linespacing above 10 it gives me what I want. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, my final snippet looks like this:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
float fntSize, lineSpacing;
fntSize = 6.7f;
lineSpacing = 10f;
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Phrase(lineSpacing,line,
               FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize)));
doc.add(p);
```

It gives a perfect format for an **A4** size paper with no margins and a good font size.

I hope it helps someone!